# Column wise modeling in Cplex using Java

Tags: java, cplex

I would like to solve a simple problem in cplex using column wise modeling.
Here is the problem,

```
maximize 2x + 3y
subject to   x<= 5
             y<=2
            x,y >=0
```

And here is the code that I have to written to solve it:

```
public static void Model_1() {
        try {
            //create new model
            IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
            //define variables
            IloNumVar x;
            IloNumVar y;
            IloObjective objective;
            objective = cplex.addMaximize();
            IloRange cons01;
            IloRange cons02;
            cons01 = cplex.addRange(0, 5, "c1");
            cons02 = cplex.addRange(0, 2, "c1");
            IloColumn new_col = cplex.column(objective, 2);
            IloColumn new_col2 = cplex.column(objective,3);
            new_col = new_col.and(cplex.column(cons01,1));
            new_col2 = new_col2.and(cplex.column(cons02,1));
            x = cplex.numVar(new_col, 0, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            y = cplex.numVar(new_col, 0, Double.MAX_VALUE);
//solve model
            if (cplex.solve()) {
                System.out.println("obj = "+cplex.getObjValue());
                System.out.println("x   = "+cplex.getValue(x));
                System.out.println("y   = "+cplex.getValue(y));
}
            else {
                System.out.println("Model not solved");
            }
            cplex.end();
        }
        catch (IloException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I am not getting the correct solution. Am I making any mistake in writing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to debug this type of problem it is always useful to export the model to LP format to make sure you generated it correctly.  You do this by adding the following line of code just before calling `cplex.solve`:

```
cplex.exportModel("model.lp");
```

If you do that, the contents of model.lp look like this:

```
Maximize
 obj: 2 x1 + 2 x2
Subject To
 c1: x1 + x2 - Rgc1  = 0
 c1: - Rgc1  = 0
Bounds
 0 <= Rgc1 <= 5
 0 <= Rgc1 <= 2
End
```

This sheds light on the two typos you've made in your program.  Namely, you should replace:

```
cons02 = cplex.addRange(0, 2, "c1");
```

with

```
cons02 = cplex.addRange(0, 2, "c2");
```

And, you should replace:

```
y = cplex.numVar(new_col, 0, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

with

```
y = cplex.numVar(new_col2, 0, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

After making those two changes model.lp looks like:

```
Maximize
 obj: 2 x1 + 3 x2
Subject To
 c1: x1 - Rgc1  = 0
 c2: x2 - Rgc2  = 0
Bounds
 0 <= Rgc1 <= 5
 0 <= Rgc2 <= 2
End
```

And, you get the following output from your program:

```
obj = 16.0
x   = 5.0
y   = 2.0
```

Comment: Hi @rkersh I was wondering can I export the model of dual problem also from Cplex?

Comment: @Dipta, if by Cplex, you mean the interactive, the answer is yes.

Comment: You told me how to do it for the above one by using cplex.exportModel("model.lp"); But if I want to export the dual formulation of the same model how should I write it? I have tried using cplex.exportModel("model.dua"). But it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Dipta, I've revised my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711690/how-can-i-export-dual-model-from-cplex-using-java.  Sorry for any confusion I may have caused there.