# Dual of models by CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I have an essential problem. I use Cplex in C++ and I try to implement my optimization programs by it; however, I have an essential problem.

I want to find dual of my program. How can I find some constructs in Cplex for C++ that do it?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711690/how-can-i-export-dual-model-from-cplex-using-java. I forgot that I had answered that one with almost exactly the same information.

Comment: You should provide code example or code samples so people get a better understanding of your issue.

Comment: @rkersh Could you check this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057420/getting-the-dual-formulation-in-cplex-concert-technology

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking for, but the [presolve dual setting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/PreDual.html) (quoting the documentation):

> Decides whether CPLEX presolve should pass the primal or dual linear
>   programming problem to the linear programming optimization algorithm.

With the C++ API, this can be set, like so:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::Preprocessing::Dual, 1);
```

Somewhat related is the [DUA file format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/brief_descrip.html):

> governed by MPS conventions, writes the dual formulation of a problem
>   currently in memory so that the MPS file can later be read back in and
>   the dual formulation can then be optimized explicitly. This file
>   format is largely obsolete now since you can use the command set
>   presolve dual in the Interactive Optimizer to tell CPLEX to solve the
>   dual formulation of an LP automatically. (You no longer have to tell
>   CPLEX to write the dual formulation to a DUA file and then tell CPLEX
>   to read the file back in and solve it.)

If, on the other hand, you want to query dual values after solving a model, you can use the [getDuals](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_getDuals) method.

Comment: Dear rkersh,Thanks so much for taking your time and also awsering my question. I will implement it. I hope that your guides help me. with my best regards.