# Getting the dual formulation in CPLEX concert technology

Tags: cplex

I have seen the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561059/dual-of-models-by-cplex) but it does not answer my question. Is there any way to get objective function and constraints of the dual formulation directly within your algorithm rather than writing them into a DUA file and then reading them? I know that I can solve the dual formulation by using

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::Preprocessing::Dual, 1);
```

But I do not want to solve the dual formulation. I want to access objective function and any constraint of the dual formulation so I could modify them as part of my algorithm. I use CPLEX 12.8 (Concert technology, C++ API) and would like to access the dual formulation within my algorithm.

Comment: Anything that you can do on the dual of your problem can be done by modifying the primal. So are you looking for the convenience of being able to manipulate the dual directly?  Or is there something more fundamental that I missed?

Comment: @XavierNodet The requested feature improves performance and certainly facilitates the job by removing some extra work and possible mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible using any of the Concert APIs (i.e., C++, Java, or .NET).

As mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=ed0a3d01-806d-42f5-93ef-a49a1e9bea51) on the IBM developerWorks forum, it is possible to do this with the C API. The Concert APIs do not allow access to the presolve model, so this is not possible.

Comment: By the way, feel free to create a [request for enhancement](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe) for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks rkersh. As mentioned in the question, I use C++ Concert technology. Is there a functionality in C++ which is equivalent to the presented solution on the IBM developerWorks for C API?

Comment: I've corrected the answer to say Concert APIs instead of Java (my bad). The answer is the same for any of the Concert API's including C++, Java, and .NET.

Comment: Request for enhancement : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=119446 and in the meantime could http://slahaie.net/docs/lpdual.pdf help ?